# Набор классов для разных проектов php

Tags: php, netbeans, репозиторий

Есть небольшой набор классов, которые используются в различных проектах.

В классы иногда вносятся изменения, различные вкусности и дополнения.

После этого приходится копировать файл измененного класса во все проекты, чтобы и там можно было автоматически использовать эти улучшения.

Есть ли возможность как-то избежать этих копирований вручную?

Допустим, указать где-то путь и имя нужного файла и пусть netbeans сам проверяет версию и копирует обновленные файлы в проект.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам подойдет composer. Это менеджер зависимостей, используемый именно для php.

Подробней можете почитать на официальном сайте проекта. https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md

Comment: composer создает загрузчик.

Мне же нужно копировать файлы из отдельного каталога в каталог проекта. Потом уже загрузчик проекта сам "найдет" их.

Comment: Вы можете создать приватный репозиторий в любом хранилище репозиториев, например github и затем сконфигурировать composer брать ваши библиотеки непосредственно из вашего приватного репозитория:

```{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}```

Comment: @VadikV и что в этом страшного?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, NetBeans вам ничем не поможет в этой задаче.
В рамках одного хоста вы можете в проектах ссылаться на библиотеки через soft link, либо настроить include_path на общие папки.
Если пользуетесь какой-нибудь vcs (надеюсь, что так!), то в репозиторий приложения можно внедрить ссылку на "внешний" репозиторий с библиотекой: svn external или git submodule.
А можно выложить библиотеку в сеть и пользоваться composer для управления зависимостями. Не хотите публичности — пользуйтесь приватными репозиториями.